# Accessing the computed properties of components in Vue from the parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do you access the computed properties of components in Vue from the parent?

In this example, I have a cart with item components and I want to compute and display the sum of the cart items:

cart.js

```
var vm = new Vue({

  el: '#cart',

  components: {
    cartItem: require('./components/cart-item.js'),
  },

  data: {
    items: [
      { name: 'apple', qty: 5, price: 5.00 },
      { name: 'orange', qty: 7, price; 6.00 },
    ],
  },

  computed: {
    // I want to do something like this and access lineTotal from cart
    cartTotal: function() {
      return this.items.reduce(function(prev,curr) {
        return prev + curr.lineTotal;
      }, 0)
    }
  }
});
```

cart-item.js

```
module.exports = {
    template: require('./cart-item.template.html'),
    props: ['fruit'],
    computed: {
      lineTotal: function() {
        return this.fruit.price * this.fruit.qty;
      }
    },
};
```

main html

```
<li v-for="item in items" is="cart-item" :fruit="item">

...

@{{ cartTotal }}
```

How do I access the `lineTotal` properties of each cart-item to use in summing `cartTotal`?

Note that I do not want to redo the calculations done in `lineTotal` but instead use the computed properties directly.

Comment: While @gurghet provided you with the technically correct answer,  I would advise against accessing the childs for stuff like this.

All the data required for the computation is present in the cart already, and the calculation is basically a one-liner. Accessing the data from the children will be at least as complicated as simply doing the calculation in the parent on its own.

Comment: The cart is a trivial example I used to illustrate the nature of my problem. Had the calculation not been a one-liner as would be from time to time, components would be a nice way to decouple the logic meant for the cart item. Do you have any suggestions other than directly accessing the child without doing the calculations on the parent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to name the children, for example by means of the `v-ref` directive. Then from the parent you resolve the children properties with `this.$refs.mychild.myproperty`

Comment: this.$refs returns an empty Object {} for me. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you set the v-ref?

Comment: Herm... I just saw your jsfiddle... more than 1 thing is wrong with it. You are using filters (`| json`) in plain javascript, also you are treating a normal `<tr>` element as if it was a component. I thing it would be better to show you a complete example so you can learn from that instead of fixing yours, which shows a somewhat strange approach to the problem. I will send you the link in this chatroom: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118302/vuejs